# Finding the Slope of a Linear Equation

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm wondering if there is an easy way to find the slope of a line. I did this yesterday and it got the correct answer. I'm not sure if my teacher told me about it or not, I don't remember. But either way I want to know if it would be "legal" to use this method. [Graph Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/obmci.jpg)

If you look closely in the picture you can see that, there is a dot in the top right and bottom left corners of each four cells. I've found that if you were to think, the line completes it's (trip?) in *four* cells, there is one line in four cells, and 1 divided by 4 is simply 1/4. If you think like 1/4 is the answer, you're correct! The problem in the image, is 1/4x + 5! Hopefully you understand... it's kind of hard to explain.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that is a legal method. Note that the slope $m$ of a linear equation is given by:
$$m=\frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x}$$
Where $\Delta y$ is the change in the $y$-coordinate and $\Delta x$ is the change in $x$-coordinate.

What you've essentially done is let $\Delta y=1$ and $\Delta x=4$. Note that you can select any two distinct points on the line and then get the same value of $m$, you've just selected integer values of the quotient which makes it easier.

Comment: Thanks! I'm glad this is legal, because personally I think it's easier.

Answer (score 1):

you can find the slope as follows $$m=\frac{y_2-y_1}{x_2-x_1}$$ if $x_1\ne x_2$

Comment: it is the same like above